# Inicialização de variáveis de instância no ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou com dificuldade em inicializar variáveis de instância no Rails, preciso utilizar uma variável em diversos métodos, mas essa precisa ser inicializada previamente, por exemplo:

```rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base    
  @test = 1

  def testar
    @test+1
  end    
end

t = Test.new
t.testar
```

Gera o seguinte erro:

```
test.rb:4:in `testar': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from test.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Pois `@test` não foi inicializado, então vejo que não funciona realizar essa inicialização no corpo da classe, existe uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso do que você usar `after_initialize`? Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
  def after_initialize
    @test = 1
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde eu sei não há outra forma recomendável, a não ser usando o `after_initialize`.

O `initialize` original da classe pode não ser invocado em alguns casos pelo ActiveRecord, então. o `after_initialize` foi criado justamente para resolver o problema de inicialização.

Há uma discussão sobre tudo isso [nesta questão do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10505166/1683070) e [neste artigo](http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html). Veja a também a [documentação explicando o `after_initialize`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find).

Answer (score 0):

Do jeito que você fez, atribuindo `@test = 1` dentro da classe, você está definindo uma variável da classe e não de instância.

Para fazer o que você quer, você pode usar o operador `||=`. Se você usa a variável em mais de um local, sugiro acessá-la através de um método de leitura.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test
    @test ||= 1
  end

  def testar
    test + 1
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.testar # => 2
```

O operador `@test ||= 1` funciona como se fosse `@test = @test || 1`.
A primeira vez que você chamar o método test, a variável @test é nil, então ele atribui 1 a @test (e retorna esse valor). Nas próximas chamadas, como @test já está definido, o método apenas retorna o valor da variável.